# nsi.pdb Cannot Load Symbol Error When I am trying to toggle breakpoint C++

Tags: c++, debugging, breakpoints, symbols, loaded

I got an error when I try to put a breakpoint to a line. It puts correctly but when I start the program it says This BP will not be currenlt hit. Because no symbols loaded.

When I take a look at modules list I saw NSI.pdb doesnt exist or couldnt be loaded Im not sure why?

I installed Debug tools for windows 86 - 64 both.

[here's the modules windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgjLw.png)

Comment: Verify that you have a pair of .DLL and .PDB file with the same timestamp. Verify that your debuggee has loaded the inteden version of the DLL. You could try to browse for the PDB file.

Comment: First thanks for your response. How Can I update both of them?

Comment: Then What Can I Do now?

Comment: I dont have source of nsi. How can I remove it?

Comment: I dont know what is it. I searched entire solution but couldnt find anything links for nsi. When I create new project BP works on it ( on same computer.) New project just loads NewProject.pdb and thats enough for it.